# How to solve the equation $ 14=\frac{100^2}{a+0.17\times 100}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asking very petty question. I am confused to solve following equation. Answer should be $9.03$. When I calculate, I constantly get different answer ($696.4$).
How would you solve? Then I wanna know where I failed.
$$
14=\frac{100^2}{a+0.17\times 100}
$$
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
14 = \frac{100^2}{a + 0.17 \times 100} = \frac{10000}{a + 17}
$$
Therefore,
$$
a + 17 = \frac{10000}{14} = \frac{5000}{7}
$$
and finally, $a = 5000/7 - 17$.

Comment: Now I am confident with my calculation with the helps of both of you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$$14=\dfrac{100^2}{(a+0.17*100)}$$

$$14(a+17)=100^2$$

$$14a+238=100^2$$

$$14a=100^2-238$$

$$a=\dfrac{100^2-238}{14}=697.285714286$$

You are correct (not entirely). Decimals and numbers are different in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$14=\frac{100^2}{a+17}$$ and then $$\frac{1}{14}=\frac{a+17}{100^2}$$ so $$\frac{100^2}{14}-17=a$$